# I am trying to debug some Javascript within a button of an xPage. Is there anyway to do this?

Tags: javascript, debugging, xpages

I have a button on an xPage that is calling some code in a jsLibrary and is not behaving correctly.  I would love to step through a debugger if possible.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I sure am.  It appears the only way is print statements at this point.  UGH.

Comment: OK, you may want to update your question. Anyway the answer seems to be below.

Comment: Prints in console long are hard to find, sometimes. My preffered method is to use scoped variables in combination with control rendering all scoped variables. You can use debug toolbar from openntf, if you don't have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to debug serverside javascript you are bound to the poormans debugger called print statements ( in Notes 9.0 you will be able to debug ssjs ).

When you need to debug CLIENTside javascript. You can use tools available for your browser.

- firefox > Firebug ( use f12 key )
- IE > Developer toolbar ( use f12 key )
- Chrome > Developer toolbar ( use f12) key)